# Simple if-else statement always returns true

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am trying to make a simple if-else statement, but when I run the code, it always returns `true`, even if I enter something in the prompt that I know should be `false`. I have [ran it through JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/16fecht/yxgf7n60/), and it seems that the code snippet is perfectly valid.

```
var captchaTest = 5;
var captchaInput = prompt('What is five plus five?');

if ('captchaTest + captchaInput = 10') {
    alert('You passed, you may continue'); window.location.href = 'pagepass.html';
}
else {
    alert('Failed, try again.'); window.location.href = 'main.html';
}
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Your syntax is wildly incorrect.  While it may parse I'm sure it won't be doing what you expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-empty strings in JavaScript are *truthy*. `'captchaTest + captchaInput = 10'`, when evaluated as Boolean, is `true`.

You need to remove the quotation marks and change `=` to `==`:

```
if (captchaTest + captchaInput == 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the answer that other provided I would also make a point that as per your captcha question, your condition should be like this

```
if (captchaInput == 10){
  alert('You passed, you may continue'); window.location.href = 'pagepass.html';
}
else {
  alert('Failed, try again.'); window.location.href = 'main.html';
}
```

I don't see any use of the variable `captchaTest`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using a `'captchaTest + captchaInput = 10'` as it is a `String` and always evaluates to `true` unless it is an empty one.

Also you should use comparison operator `==` instead of assignment operator `=`

So remove the quotes

```
if ((captchaTest + captchaInput) == 10)
```